# can a foreign key column refernce a unique column in the parent table where it contains a NULL?

Tags: sql

In SQL, can you set a column that allows null values to be unique? What happens if the table contains multiple rows with null value for that column? What happens in case you specify a foreign key to that column in another table and a tuple in the referencing table contains a null value for the foreign key?

I am only concerned with the last part of the question!!

Thank you

Comment: You can only have one NULL then

Comment: Please add the table design you want to create. Sounds like you are doing something wrong

Comment: i know I can have one NULL but my question is can a foreign key reference a NULL tuple @TimSchmelter thank you

Comment: I am not designing a table it is a theoretical question @juergend

Comment: Yes.  The only specification is that the column be `unique`.  Some databases allow multiple `NULL` values in a unique column; some do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you set a column that allows null values to be unique?

If you are talking about `UNIQUE` constraint on that column then conceptually **YES** but the column can have utmost one `NULL` value. Again depends one RDBMS type since few RDBMS allows multiple nulls.

> What happens in case you specify a foreign key to that column in
>   another table and a tuple in the referencing table contains a null
>   value for the foreign key?

Yes you can do that but but in that case don't define any `UNIQUE` constraint on that column. rather define it as a nullable column.